# Javascript replace opening and closing brackets

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I have a string of text, for example

```
[text1] [text2] [text3]
```

I want to replace "[" character with "${" and "]" character with  "}", but only in that case, when "[" is followed up by "]".

For example

```
[text1] [[text2] [text3]
```

should result in

```
${text1} [${text2} ${text3}
```

How can I accomplish that with regex in Javascript?

I wrote something like this

```
someString = someString.replace(/\[/g, "${");
someString = someString.replace(/]/g, "}");
```

But it doesn't work for my problem, it just replaces every bracket.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You may use

```js
var s = "[text1] [[text2] [text3]";
console.log(s.replace(/\[([^\][]+)]/g, "$${$1}"));
```

**Details**

- `\[` - a `[` char
- `([^\][]+)` - Group 1: a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) matching any 1+ chrs other than `[` and `]` (note that inside a character class in a JS regex, the `]` char must always be escaped, even if it is placed at the negated class start)
- `]` -  a `]` char (outside of a character class, `]` is not special and does not have to be escaped).

In the replacement pattern, `$$` stands for a literal `$` char, `{` adds a `{` char, `$1` inserts the Group 1 value and then a `}` is added.