# javascript - find and replace only matching closing bracket

Tags: javascript

I'm wondering if there's an elegant way to find and replace the matching brackets for code depending on what is adjacent to the opening bracket. For example, I might want to convert:

```
// code for random_number() function
for(i in 1:5){
   print(i);
   mean(c(1,2,random_number()))
   sd(c(4,5,6))
}
```

into:

```
// code for random_number() function
for(i in 1:5){
   print(i);
   mean([1,2,random_number()])
   sd([4,5,6])
}
```

because all I want to do is convert "c(1,2,3)" into "[1,2,3]" (and "c(4,5,6)" into "[4,5,6]"). I want to identify the closing bracket opposite "c(" in a script like this.

I don't want to change any of the other opening and closing brackets. Is there an elegant way of doing this? The closest thing I found was [Javascript replace opening and closing brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52062279/javascript-replace-opening-and-closing-brackets), but it seemed more like a method to replace all brackets with the occasional exception, rather than specific brackets but ignoring most.

My only thoughts are to count the opening and closing of brackets, but that seems quite ugly, to say the least. Is there a tidier way?

Comment: What about `func(1,2,3)`?

Comment: Sorry - I'm not sure I follow, can you elaborate please? (the numbers are just example numbers btw if that's relevant)

Comment: There could be functions ending with `c` with parameters like `(a, b, c)` not being arrays. `func(1, 2, 3)` would, according to your written logic, end up being replaced with `fun[1, 2, 3]`. I do not know your usecase nor environment - just something to be aware of.

Comment: That... that is an excellent point. Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use RegExp for that, something like: `c\((([^)]*\([^)]*\))*[^)]*)\)`
Here is an example:

```js
const regExp = /c\((([^)]*\([^)]*\))*[^)]*)\)/g;
const source = `// code for random_number() function
for(i in 1:5){
   print(i);
   mean(c(1,2,random_number()))
   sd(c(4,5,6))
}`;
const result = source.replace(regExp, '[$1]')
console.log(result);
```

This will probably fail with more complex source strings.

What it does, is to look for a `c` character followed by a `(` character, then ignore all opening brackets that have a corresponding closing bracket and put all that along with any characters that are not a `)` into a group and then look for a `)` character.

Balancing parenthesis with regex is not a good idea, this works with only one level (fails when there are two opening parenthesis without a closing parenthesis between them). A more reliable approach will be looping the string and keeping track of all the opening and closing brackets.

Beside all that, the regex doesn't distinguish between brackets that are part of code or those that are part of string literals.

Comment: agreed with titus - so far this seems to address my problem (will probably accept once I've done a few checks)

Comment: actually, sorry, yes, that is a problem: I'm looking for a way that `mean(c(1,2,giveMeARandomNumber()))` becomes `mean([1,2,giveMeARandomNumber()])`, not `mean([1,2,giveMeARandomNumber(]))` - I'll update my question to address this

Comment: @Lain Yes, it does. I've edited my answer to address that.

Comment: @Lain I've replaced `?` with `*` and those kind of cases are covered now as well.

Comment: just tried it on a = c(1,2,num(),beep(),bop(),brap()) - works nicely! - I think exceptions as described below require can be addressed by me identifying what is in a string (which this solution does!) and then dealing with edge cases like that.

Comment: @Lain Actually, they are not handled correctly. Like I've said in the answer, *this will probably fail for more complex strings*

Comment: I've actually tried to do this before (balancing parentheses) with regex and determined that it cannot be done correctly (or at least I can't) but decided to post an answer anyway. I deserve all the scrutiny. I will add a disclosure to the answer so that others will not try to use this without knowing it will most then probably fail.

Comment: To address the c(c(c(...etc...))) issue, could you not use a while loop:
const result = source.replace(regExp, '[$1]')
var cs_to_resolve = true;
  
  while(cs_to_resolve == true){
    if(source !== source.replace(regExp, '[$1]')){
      source = source.replace(regExp, '[$1]');
    } else {
      cs_to_resolve = false;
    }
  }